# Changing file extensions, content being deleted

Tags: python

I am stole a little script that is supposed to simply add an extension where none exists from a file export. But when I run it, I get results and the actual content from the files has thus been zeroed out.

Why is this happening?

```
import os, sys

path = 'C:/Users/jal!/Downloads/Sinopiadata/'

for file in os.listdir(path):

    if file != "complete.log" and file != "jasawn.py":
        os.chdir('C:/Users/jal!/Downloads/Sinopiadata/')
        file = (file)
        filename = file + ".json"
        filename = open(filename,'w')
```

Comment: What's the point of `file = (file)`?

Comment: If `file` was originally `foo`, you didn't empty `foo`; you just created a new empty file named `foo.json`. `foo` still exists unchanged.

Comment: yes, this is what is happening! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't put anything into the new file. If you want to copy from the file without the extension to the file with the extension, you have to read and write.

```
for file in os.listdir(path):

    if file != "complete.log" and file != "jasawn.py":
        os.chdir('C:/Users/jal!/Downloads/Sinopiadata/')
        file = (file)
        filename = file + ".json"
        with open(filename,'w') as newfile, open(file, 'r') as oldfile:
            newfile.write(oldfile.read())
```

You can also use [`shutil.copyfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile)

Answer (score 3):

There's always the rename method you can *(or should, as mentioned in the comments)* use:

```
import os

os.rename(file, file_with_extension)
```

Comment: Not just *can*, but *should*. There's no reason to open the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = open(filename,'w')
```

opens the file for writing in truncating mode, which is why it gets emptied. There's no point in having that line there at all if you're only renaming things. You should just use `os.rename(old_path, new_path)`.

Comment: How does he create the file without that line?

Comment: Thank you EVERYONE. It appears to have run successfully! Simple file renaming with the extension. I appreciate it. cheerz